# How should I flag questions trying to get around the "This post is mostly code" filter?

Tags: discussion, flags, quality-filter

I was scrolling through one of my tabs when I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47077836/how-do-i-get-my-calculator-to-work-with-decimals). Obviously, this is completely against site policy and is blatantly trying to get around the "post is mostly code" quality filter; however, I don't know how to flag this type of behaviour.

I'm specifically asking about questions which are trying to subvert the quality filter, not questions of a similar style or type to the linked question above.

What's the general advice for flagging these questions? I flagged it as "Too Broad" in this case, but I wasn't sure whether there were any other flags which are more appropriate.

Comment: Start by downvoting and voting to close.  If you also want to cast a mod flag for intentional abuse of quality filters, it's certainly a thing you could do, I guess.

Comment: That filter is in place to help users post good questions. It's not a spam filter. Handle it as any other question (noting that questions that have to avoid the filter pretty much can't be MCVE, so a close vote will likely be appropriate).

Comment: In this particular case, I would close as too broad, though no minimal example would work too.

Comment: I voted as "Too Broad" on this question, I just wanted to ensure that I was following the correct thought process.

Comment: @gnat I'm not referring to the fact the user is asking a debugging question, more what actions should be taken against posts which are specifically trying to subvert the quality filter.

Comment: There's a good argument to be made for flagging [these types of posts](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47077836/1) as "rude/abusive"—the logic being that blatant attempts to bypass our quality filters are abusive behavior. I have no problem with this, and have dispatched such questions in this way several times. On the other hand, not everyone agrees with me on this, including other mods, so reception of such flags may be mixed. A "weaker" flag that would achieve a similar effect would be "very low quality", but that flag type is ill-defined, too. Maybe best to just DV + flag for closure.

Comment: @CodyGray could you please include a screenshot of the post itself, as has been deleted, so that way others can see the problem?

Comment: Sometimes someone posts a bad question, but it seems like they might not have known it was a bad question, so I give them the benefit of the doubt and shake my head sympathetically as I gently click the downvote button. Other times like this example, when someone obviously posted a bad question _on purpose_, I scowl and mercilessly click the downvote button while mentally quoting Captain Ahab "from hell’s heart I stab at thee", etc. This approach may not work for everyone.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: I'm not sure that's the best quote to use as it involved the death of Ahab. Perhaps a quote where the protagonist *survives* would be more apt :-)

Comment: The question got deleted. Could somebody with more than 10k reputation please post a screenshot of it?

Comment: @paxdiablo true, I have survived all my downvotes so far. I guess I was thinking of the attitude more than the outcome.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I'm glad to know that giving out downvotes isn't lethal, that's a load off my mind...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Personally, I usually used custom mod-flags for cases like this (I haven't done it in a while), but there are some other options:

- **Edit to shorten their code.** Take out any lines that don't affect the reproducibility of the problem. Minimize their Complete and Verifiable Example.
- If it's truly pure code, **flag/vote to close.** This would be Unclear What You're Asking, or Debugging Help under off-topic.
- If it's asking how to shorten or simplify the code, then it belongs on Code Review. **VtC as Too Broad.**

Comment: That last one seems strange, to VtC as too broad for something which is off-topic. I mean it *probably* is too broad so technically it wouldn't be wrong, but the signal should be clear: it's *definitely* off-topic, don't ask these kind of questions on Stack Overflow (but potentially somewhere else).

Comment: @Gimby Code Review isn't a migration target yet so Too Broad is what we close it as.

Comment: @StephenLeppik [Migrating low-quality questions to another site doesn't solve the issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82941/please-dont-migrate-low-quality-questions-to-other-sites). I highly doubt that Code Review would want these types of posts.

Comment: Doesn't seem off-topic to me, but to each his own...